# Render inline formset with ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, inline-formset

I have two models Model1 and Model2, where Model2 contains a Foreignkey to some other model (Say Model3). I am using django inline formset to add and edit information related to Model1. Below is the Formset that I have created, the md_attributes in the fields is the ForeignKey field to Model3.

```
inline_form_set = inlineformset_factory(Model1, Model2, fields =('md_attributes', 'val',), max_num=0, can_delete=False, extra=0)
```

The template to render the formset is

```
{{ formset.management_form }}

{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.id }}
    {{ form.md_attributes}}: {{ form.val }} <br><br>
{% endfor %}

 <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"><br><br>
<input class="btn" formaction="{% url 'projects:admin_projects_info' project_name %}"
           type="submit" name="submit" value="Cancel">
```

With the above template code, the formset is rendered as Foreignkey choices(Choice Field) and a Textinput field. But what I try to achieve is to render the foreign key choices as static labels in the formset like below

Choice1 : Some Value,
 Choice2 : Othe Value

I tried creating a list of choices and then use it in the for loop (template), but with that my post request is creating an error. I also think that's not an efficient way to solve this problem. Any valuable input is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must sent back each field in a POST on form submission. If you try to render the value as `<p>{ value }</p>` for example, you will need to include somewhere in the form `<input type="hidden" value="{ value }"/>` so the browser includes the field in the POST.

This can easily be manipulated by nefarious users, so it is important to validate the data when it returns to the server. One such way is to store the initial value of the field in the form's **init** and to restore that in clean no matter what is sent back in POST.